# C language cannot print array[i][j]

Tags: c, printf

In C language,

I have an array[3][2];

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        printf("%d", array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

When I use gcc to compile .c file, the error shows:

```
format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

How to print an array using C?

Comment: How did you declare your array? Was it `int *array[3][2];`?

Comment: Show the array declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems pretty straight forward. It's telling you that `array[i][j]` is of type `int*`, while the `printf()` "%d" formatter is expecting an argument of type `int`.

I'm not sure what you expect to happen here. You haven't shown us how you declare `array`. But, if it's supposed to be a two-dimensional array of `int`, then you declared it wrong.